# Setting href for .less stylesheet through JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, less

I'm using cookies to find out if the user is in light or dark mode onload of body. I always use the light.less as the fallback/default if a cookie can't be found. So in my `<head>` I have

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" id="colorMode" href="../assets/light.less">
<script src="../assets/less.js/dist/less.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and my body tag is as follows:

```
<body onload="checkNav(); checkCookies();" onresize="checkNav()">
```

The `checkCookies()` is the function to review the cookie and act accordingly, it is shown below.

```
function checkCookies() {
var style = getCookie("style");
if (style == 'dark') {
    document.getElementById("colorMode").href = "../assets/dark.less";
    document.getElementById("switchIcon").innerHTML = "toggle_on";
    document.cookie = "style=dark; path=/~sam.walker";
} 

else {
        //Already set by default
    }
}
```

*The `getCookie()` function simply returns the relevant style cookie*

The `colorMode` stylesheet with href = `../assets/light.less` does change as expected to `../assets/dark.less` as I've checked with inspector but the style itself does not physically change. I've checked cache and its nothing to do with that. Any help would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: You must add a .css file, not a .less file. A browser can't parse/understand a less file

Comment: Even when linking to less.js using `<script src="../assets/less.js/dist/less.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`? The .less files run fine, as long as they are set before loading the site, only have this effect when trying to change the sheet through JS.

Comment: As soon as you use any less syntax it will stop working though... Also you will need to dynamically insert the css file into `head` after you determine the theme. Or you can have a base css, then load 2 lightweight themes which apply themselves based on a body class

Answer (score 0):

Including the stylesheet as a `.less` format won't work unless you have `<script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` added within the `<head>` section of your page.

Check out the usage information from Less.js [here](http://lesscss.org/usage/)

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained that I already link to that, I forgot to mention it in the post and have edited accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

`less.min.js` will find references to LESS files and generates CSS from them when it loads.

You are creating a new reference to a LESS file **after** that, by which time it is too late for `less.js` to notice.

You need to call `checkCookies();` after you have linked to the LESS stylesheet but before you load the `less.js` script.

Comment: Is there any way to reload `less.js` on event. Such as `onclick=`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help,

Through your info I have found the following (*botch*) fix:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('NameOfOriginalLessGeneratedStyle'); //REQUIRES CHANGE ON SERVER CHANGE
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
//Deleted previous styles
less.refresh();
//Loads new style
```

Should run after stylesheet href change.